# How to specify a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I want to generify a class instantiation in the following code:

Old code:

```
public abstract class Test{
    public static Test instantiate(Class clazz)throws Exception{ //instance of clazz extends Test
        return (Test)clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Because any instance of parameter `clazz` would be extending class `Test`,  I would like to achieve something like this:

```
public static T <T extends Test> instantiate(Class<? extends Test> clazz){
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

It is giving the following compile error:

```
Unspecified Bound
```

How to do it using java generics?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Test` and `Application` in your first code snippet? Does `Application` inherit `Test`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mixed up the order. This is the correct syntax:

```
public static <T extends Test> T instantiate(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Note that `Class<? extends Test>` has been changed to `Class<T>`. You also need to take care of any possible exceptions of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public static <T extends Test> T instantiate(Class<T> clazz)
throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```